# Automatically Overwrite files and skip new files

Tags: windows, bash

How can I overwrite existing files on destination (corrupt files) but don't copy other files from source

I can't collect existing files from source and no more free disk space available on destination to add new files

Both Windows apps or bash script can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
rsync --existing SRCDIR/* DESTDIR/
```

If you want it to be recursive

```
rsync -r --existing SRCDIR/* DESTDIR/
```